# fedora : no space left on device while compiling mptcp kernel

Tags: fedora

I have to install MPTCP Kernel on my fc16. On my fc16, I had the base kernel of 3.1

I updated the kernel. Next i went for Linux Kernel 3.2.

Once all this was done. I got mptcp source from github and configured everything as per the manual in menuconfig.

Now when I try to compile using "sudo make" - I get this error -

"ld : link error : no space left on device"

I have allocated 20 GB to my box. How to get around this?

This is my df output in /

[root@localhost /]# df -T
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs         rootfs    18574076 18497656         0 **100%** /
devtmpfs       devtmpfs   1012192        0   1012192   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      1023200      224   1022976   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs      1023200      576   1022624   1% /run
/dev/xvda3     ext3      18574076 18497656         0 100% /
tmpfs          tmpfs      1023200        0   1023200   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs      1023200        0   1023200   0% /media

[root@localhost /]#

I can see that rootfs is 100% used. How to go ahead and free this?

Comment: What does "I have allocated 20 GB on my box" mean?  Is this a virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, this is a virtual machine

Answer (score 2):

You have run out of disk space, you can verify this with the `df` command.

Note: try to delete the source of the previous kernel or do a `make clean` there.

Comment: karoly, in my /usr/src directory, I have linux3.2 and mptcp. Currently I have linux3.2 installed. So where should I do a make clean?

Comment: sorry I thought the old kernel was compiled too... well, just free up some space...